# need help to move the toolbar to the top of the sentrum div

Tags: html, css, toolbar

I need help with moving tool bar present that are directed on the picture had been of great help.

[picture link below refer to what I talk about in the above text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV2uY.png)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g0vxw1ft/

Comment: Explain what you want.  Don't make us click links.